# Cannot do actions on the secondary window with FEST/swing

Tags: java, swing, fest

public class DemoTest {

```
private FrameFixture demo;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    demo = new FrameFixture(new Demo());
}

@After
public void tearDown() {

    demo.cleanUp();
}

@Test
public void test() {


    demo.button("myButtonFromTheMainFrame").click(); //on the main frame is happening
    demo.button("myButtonFromTheSecondFrame").click();//here it is not happening
}
```

}

I have a minimum SWING Frame configuration which contains a button that when it gets clicked it opens a new frame (the main frame is still on).
This secondary frame has another button but I cannot do any automated tests anymore on the second frame.
I tried with this solution:

Robot robot = BasicRobot.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy();

FrameFixture frame = WindowFinder.findFrame("Title of my frame").using(robot);

but any action that I am doing on the secondary frame is not happening...so the button is not getting clicked on the 2nd one, only on the first

I haven't found any solution on this issue when a new window gets opened and start doing automated tests on it.
Can somebody give me some advices? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set the focus on the second frame before 2nd button click?

Comment: No but I will try to do that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: To be clear, "Title of my frame" is the title of the secondary frame? Have you tried reusing `demo`'s robot (`demo.robot()`) instead of creating a new one?

Comment: yes, it is of the 2nd frame...haven't tried using demo.robot()...i will check...thanks!